# Use an array/list as VLOOKUP search key

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have two sets of data. The first is an ever growing list of names, which we'll call `Names` (not necessarily a named range). Something like:

```
John
Bill
Bob
Steve
```

The second is also a growing set of data, includes (but is not limited to) the above names, and has some corresponding values. We'll call this `Data`.

```
John    4
Jack    7
Bill    6
Jane    1
Bob     9
Steve   10
```

What I'd like to do is iterate through `Data`, looking any items defined in `Names`, then summing their corresponding values. In this case, it'd return `29` (4+6+9+10).

I immediately thought to use VLOOKUP, as that's the normal function to use for matters like this. However, VLOOKUP seems to only accept a single value as its search key, so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your names are in H1:H4, and your data is in J1:K6. Then to obtain the sum you want use the formula:

```
=sum(arrayformula(vlookup(H1:H4, J1:K6, 2, false)))
```

The key to the solution is obviously ARRAYFORMULA, which takes a single-argument VLOOKUP and iterates it over an array of arguments.

Comment: @pnuts took me a while to wrap my head around why this was working, but working it is. thanks!

Comment: To accommodate an ever growing list, it should be enough in my formula to replace H1:H4 with H:H, etc.